# How to add ARC enable .a files to non-ARC project in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

How to add ARC enable .a files to non-ARC project in xcode. Because I try to add Spotify library(enable ARC .a file) to my current project that is non-ARC project.
Give your help.
thanks

Comment: It's supposed to work. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work `Check you are using the newest Apple compiler with this non-ARC project` and not the GCC one.

and Check this link for detailed info. [mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries](http://www.exactmagic.com/mixing-arc-and-non-arc-code-with-static-libraries/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The link that you provided is down. Please fix it